# Cannot find module 'pinia' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, pinia

I'm working on a Vue+Quasar project and trying to switch the store from Vuex to Pinia.  I installed Pinia but I'm still getting an error message in PyCharm saying "Cannot find module 'pinia' or its corresponding type declarations".

[image]

Comment: How did you install? and does it exist in node_modules?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I installed with "yarn add pinia", and yes, there is a "pinia" folder in my node_modules folder.

Comment: Sometimes I close/reopen the editor and the warning disappear

Comment: On the right hand side of your InteliJ IDE you'll see a `Typescript x.y.z`. Click on it and select `Restart TypeScript Service`. If that doesn't fix it (it does in 90% of cases), `File > Repair IDE...` and follow instructions. If you don't have a `Repair IDE...` option in `File` menu (maybe upgrade it?), go with `Invalidate caches...`.

Comment: Since I've posted this question I've realized that switching a Quasar project from Vuex to Pinia may be so complicated as to make it preferable to just create a new Quasar project, select Pinia in the CLI's options, and copy over my source code.  For an example of another difficulty I'm having: in my existing project `quasar create store` is creating Vuex stores, and I can't figure out how to switch it to create Pinia stores.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using Webstorm 2022.3, and reopening the IDE does the trick. This might be an IDE issue that fails to reload node_module index information.

Comment: As this is just a suggestion, you should use the comment-function on the question for answers like this one

Comment: @YvesHendseth What's your rationale?